Как отправить кружок (круглое видео) в Telegram API? C# WTelegramClient
Я использую библиотеку WTelegramClient для работы с апи телеграмма (не бота).
Возможно ли отправить круглое видео используя эту библиотеку?

@S.H., чем не устроило слово "кружок"?

@Qwertiy - я постарался исправить так, чтобы мне самому стало понятно, о чем речь. Слово "кружок" мне было вообще непонятно. Если я не прав - переименуйте назад?

@S.H., ну, пусть автор решает, но вообще https://i.sstatic.net/6M98JvBM.png

@Qwertiy век живи - век учись! исправил заголовок еще раз :-)
